# Solution $x:\mathbb R_+\to [0,1]$ of the ODE $\dot x = \tfrac 1 2 x^2 - (1-x) (1-e^{-at})$ is a concave function of $g(t)=1-e^{-at}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, nonlinear-analysis

> Is any solution $x_t:\mathbb R_+\to [0,1]$ of the ODE $\dot x = \tfrac 1 2 x^2 - (1-x) (1-e^{-at})$ is a concave function of $g_t=1-e^{-at}$ for any $a>0$?

**Note:** A solution has to converge to the critical point $x_* = \sqrt{3}-1$, otherwise it would explode (and leave the interval $[0,1]$, so it won't be a solution). There is in fact unique such solution.

This is a simplification of the question: [Convexity / concavity of $(g_t,x_t)$, where $x_t$ solves the ODE $\dot x_t=\tfrac 1 2 x_t^2 - (1-x_t) g_t$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611248/convexity-of-g-t-x-t-given-by-a-solution-of-the-quadratic-one-variable-ode), which is a simplification of my original problem: [System of quadratic autonomous ODEs - convexity of the solution curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608055/system-of-quadratic-autonomous-odes-convexity-of-the-solution-curve)

A slightly more general question would be:

> Is any solution $x:\mathbb R_+\to [0,1]$ of the ODE $\dot x = \tfrac 1 2 x^2 - b(1-x) (1-e^{-at})$ a concave function of $g_t=1-e^{-at}$ for any $a,b>0$?

I will appreciate a solution or a reference to any similar problems.

Comment: If it is interesting, I have managed to find that $x(g)=$
$$\frac{2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a)^{n+1}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2a}\right)(1-g)^n}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1-\sqrt3}{2a}\right)\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2a}+1\right)}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a)^n\Gamma\left(n+\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2a}\right)(1-g)^n}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1-\sqrt3}{2a}+1\right)\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2a}+1\right)}}.$$

Comment: I don't find this formula very useful, especially because I asked this question with the hope to get a key for answering it for more general functions $g$. However, it makes me wonder how did you obtain it, did you use Mathematica and some tricks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142106/discussion-between-user777777777-and-pavel-kocourek).